# spark select column returns reference of old dataframe

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I use the following code:

```
random = [("ABC",xx, 1), 
          ("DEF",yy,1), 
          ("GHI",zz, 0) 
         ]
randomColumns = ["name","id", "male"]
randomDF = spark.createDataFrame(data=random, schema = randomColumns)
test_df = randomDF.select("name", "id")
test_df.filter(f.col("male") == '1').show()
```

From the above code I expect it to result in an error because for the test_df i dont select the male column from the original dataframe. Surprisingly the above query runs just fine without any error and outputs the following:

```
+---------+-------+
|name     |     id|
+---------+-------+
|      abc|     xx|
|      def|     yy|
+---------+-------+
```

I want to understand the logic behind what spark is doing. As per the spark documentation Select returns a new dataframe. Then why is it still able to use the male column from the parent dataframe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is caused by the DAG generated by Spark. Some operators (or `transformers`) is are lazy-executed, so they pave the way for Spark to optimize the DAG.

In this example, there are two major steps: `select` (or `project` in SQL's jargon） first, and `filter` later. But in fact, when executing, `filter` first, and then `select`, because it is more efficient.

You can verify this conclusion by `explain()` method:

```py
test_df.filter(f.col("flag") == '1').explain()
```

It will output:

```
== Physical Plan ==
*(1) Project [dept_name#0, dept_id#1L]
+- *(1) Filter (isnotnull(flag#2L) AND (flag#2L = 1))
   +- *(1) Scan ExistingRDD[dept_name#0,dept_id#1L,flag#2L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @chenzhongpu 's answer, please note that if you define a temp view on top of your `test_df`, the query will fail:

```
test_df.createOrReplaceTempView("test_df")
spark.sql("select * from test_df where flag = 1").show()
_Traceback (most recent call last): ...
:
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: u"cannot resolve '`flag`' given input columns: [test_df.dept, test_df.id]; line 1 pos 24;
'Project [*]
 +- 'Filter ('flag = 1)
   +- SubqueryAlias `test_df`
      +- Project [dept#0, id#2L]
         +- LogicalRDD [dept#0, flag#1L, id#2L], false
 _
```

...because a `select` (=`Project` node in the execution plan) is going to precede filter (attempted via `where` clause).